# Can you assign a function to a variable in C#?

Tags: c#

i saw a function can be define in javascript like

```
var square = function(number) {return number * number};
```

and can be called like

```
square(2);

var factorial = function fac(n) {return n<3 ? n : n*fac(n-1)};
print(factorial(3));
```

### c# code

```
MyDelegate writeMessage = delegate ()
                              {
                                  Console.WriteLine("I'm called");
                              };
```

so i need to know that can i define a function in the same way in c#. if yes then just give a small snippet of above like function definition in c# please. thanks.

Comment: As a sidenote (I keep saying this whenever it pops up), in C#, you'd typically speak of *methods*, not of functions.

Comment: @stakx Strictly speaking, function is the correct terminology here. It's not a coincidence that `Func` is named `Func`.

Comment: @chibacity: `Func` as a delegate type is appropriately named, as it represents the *idea* of a function. However, in the C# language, there are no functions. You'll only ever subscribe methods to the delegate (even if they're anonymous). The term "function" is simply not appropriate in the context of C#.

Comment: @stakx I disagree, it's semantically useful terminology. It embeds the fact that there is a return value, and to be pure as in this example, has no side effects. The term "method" does not indicate this.

Comment: @chibacity: I need to take a step back to explain. The reason I mentioned this bit of terminology advice in the first place was to get the OP to recognise a difference between the JavaScript and C# languages, and that it is almost always wrong to call methods "functions". But you are right: While C# as a language does not have functions (as a syntactic construct), I concede that the *concept*, or *idea*, of a function can still be represented, e.g. with the `Func` delegates.

Comment: @stakx Agreed, I just originally assumed the OP already knows the basics of methods and functions in C# and JS. The term is unfortunately overloaded.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can create delegate type declaration:

```
delegate int del(int number);
```

and then assign and use it:

```
   del square = delegate(int x)
    {
        return x * x;
    };

    int result= square (5);
```

Or as said, you can use a "shortcut" to delegates (it made from delegates) and use:

```
Func<[inputType], [outputType]> [methodName]= [inputValue]=>[returnValue]
```

for example:

`Func<int, int> square = x=>x*x;`
`int result=square(5);`

You also have two other shortcuts:
Func with no parameter: `Func<int> p=()=>8;`
Func with two parameters: `Func<int,int,int> p=(a,b)=>a+b;`

Comment: why do I recieve "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" error if I call square(5)?

Answer (score 26):

```
Func<double,double> square = x => x * x;

// for recursion, the variable must be fully
// assigned before it can be used, therefore
// the dummy null assignment is needed:
Func<int,int> factorial = null;
factorial = n => n < 3 ? n : n * factorial(n-1);
```

Any of the following more verbose forms is possible, too: (I'm using `square` as an example):

- `Func<double,double> square = x => { return x * x; };`
  The expression is expanded to a statement block.
- `Func<double,double> square = (double x) => { return x * x; };`
  Explicit parameter list instead of just one parameter with inferred type.
- `Func<double,double> square = delegate(double x) { return x * x; };`
  This one uses the older "anonymous delegate" syntax instead of so-called "lambda expressions" (`=>`).

**P.S.:** `int` might not be an appropriate return type for a method such as `factorial`. The above examples are only supposed to demonstrate *syntax*, so modify them as necessary.