# Expression-bodied method: Return nothing

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I was updating one of our projects to C# 6.0 when I found a method that was literally doing nothing:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    return;
}
```

Now I was wondering if there is any possibility to rewrite it as an expression-bodied method as it just contains `return`.

**Try 1:**

```
private void SomeMethod() => return;
```

*Exceptions:*

> 1. ; expected
> 2. Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
> 3. Invalid expression term 'return'

**Try 2:**

```
private void SomeMethod() => ;
```

*Exception:*

> 1. Invalid expression term ';'

Is there any possibility to achieve this (although this method doesn't really make sense)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not an expression body, but you can do this:

```
private void SomeMethod() { }
```

Comment: Your second example throws the exception 'Invalid expression term '{''.

Comment: @diiN_ My bad. I thought the syntax was the same as lambdas, but apparently not

Comment: I noticed you *can* do this:

`private void NOPMethod(){}

private void SomeMethod() => NOPMethod();`

Answer (score 4):

Methods which do nothing still make sense - they just do nothing.

You can lose the return statement:

```
  private void SomeMethod() { }
```

Or [assign a function to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056041/assign-a-function-to-a-variable-in-c-sharp) instead:

```
  private Action SomeMethod = () => { };
```

Comment: Your second example does not compile. `private Action SomeMethod = () => { };` does, but I think it's a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, i have updated the answer. Yes its a bad idea, I had never done it before and guessed wrong.

Comment: I noticed you *can* do this:

`private void NOPMethod(){}

private void SomeMethod() => NOPMethod();`

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to do expression for body on void function, you can do this:

```cs
private void SomeFunction() => Expression.Empty();
```

This uses Linq and creates an empty expression that has Void type.