# Is it possible to add methods into variables

Tags: c#, variables, methods

Is it possible to add methods into variables, example being.

```
public static int BoolToInt(bool entry)
{
    if(entry == true) { return 1; }
    else { return 0; }
}

bool example = checkbox1.Checked;
RandomMethod(example.BoolToInt());
```

Looking into minimizing visual clutter and help readability (I find `RandomMethod(example.BoolToInt(), example2.BoolToInt());` easier to read than `RandomMethod(BoolToInt(example), BoolToInt(example2));`) I was wondering if this was possible, upon research I found this [Can you assign a function to a variable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056041/can-you-assign-a-function-to-a-variable-in-c) which feels like it's the right direction, but it makes the variable become the method, when I want to just add into it. I'm a newbie so I couldn't go from there to what I want nor know if it's theres a way to do it, also couldn't find much reading the Microsoft Docs.

Comment: You are looking for [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: Note that if you do decide to use an extension method on a primitive type (which is a dubious practice), be sure to make the containing class `internal`. Otherwise you may bother a lot of code with an extension method they did not expect to be there.

Comment: Oh, thats perfect thank you, any performance issues I need to be aware of, or that works basically the same as regularly calling methods?

Comment: An extension method is just a static method and has the exact same performance as an ordinary static method.

Comment: If we want to convert, why don't we convert: `Convert.ToInt32(example)`? `Convert` is evident, when purpose of `BoolToInt` is not that clear

Comment: How is `BoolToInt`/`ToInt` not clear on it's purpose? I see it the same way I see `ToString()`, but again I'm a newbie so I don't know if theres a convention that this would be conflicting with or something along the same lines.

Comment: Typically, when one wants to extend a type, inheritance is the approach. But `bool` is a value type and can't be inherited. For situations where you want to extend a type in a way that can be done using only public members of the type **extension methods** are the language feature you want. See duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C# extension methods to "extend" exists types by declaring new methods for the extended type.

```cs
static class BoolExtensions {
  public static int ToInt(this bool value) {
    return value ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

Then you can use as:

```cs
var example = true;
var exampleAsInt = example.ToInt();
```

##### Reference:

- [Extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Comment: Or `public static int ToInt(this bool value) => Convert.ToInt32(value);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `(int) value` is also enough. I just wanted to help on extension part, question was not about boolean to int conversion.

Comment: Yes it was about doing the extensions, using this conversion was a bad example